# Array, Vector, Map and List data searching

Tags: c++, arrays, list, vector, dictionary

I'm currently working on a C++ school assignment and I have 3 object types. Customer, Hire and Tour. Customer is liked to Tour and Hire. Requirement is to use Array, Vector, Map and List to hold this information based on users's selection of the data structure type. There are data files with 1000s of records and the application will read them  and create the necessary objects. For a example if the user selects vector, it'll create 3 vectors containing above objects. Then following operations will be preformed on them.

- load in the large datasets we have provided for you. If the
  datastructure you are using  supports sorting, it should be sorted by
  description.
- Prepare a list of customers whose have booked a tour that will occur
  before the end of  the year
- Prepare a list of tours booked by customers who owe us more than
  $2000, sorted by the  date their account is due
- Prepare a list of Hires by customers whose postcodes begin with a 5

I have following in my main application header file.

private:

```
string structureType;

Customer** customerListArray;
Tour** tourListArray;
EquipmentHire** equipmentsListArray;

vector<Customer *> customerListVector;
vector<Tour *> tourListVector;
vector<EquipmentHire *> equipmentsListVector;

std::map<string, Customer*> customerListMap;
std::map<string, Tour*> tourListMap;
std::map<string, EquipmentHire*> equipmentsListMap;

list<Customer *> customerListList;
list<Tour *> tourListList;
list<EquipmentHire *> equipmentsListList;
```

Then I load data on to those objects based on the user's selection. However my question is, Do I need to write different functions for each type of data structures to preform above operations, or is there a common interface I can use on all of them?

My C++ knowledge is very limited and requirement is to use C++98.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common interface is "STL container."  This is not a strong interface defined in C++, but is a concept that you can rely on all STL containers to implement.  You can therefore use templates to write code once that will apply to all of them.

(Note that maps and vectors differ in that maps have `std::pair<>` as their element type.  In practice this can be worked around by providing "identity" and "map" selectors to your search function.)